# When SonarQube scans the Git Submodule project, only the files of the super project are scanned

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, sonarqube, git-submodules

When SonarQube scans the Git submodule project, only the files of the super project are scanned.
Run in jenkins(Linux)
SonarQube version is 7.9.3
a maven project

the super project:
[image: only 2 file： .gitmodules and pom.xml]

in other project，maven project have module，but not use git submodule can work.

the log:
only 1 file, the pom.xml for super project are scanned.

```
[INFO] User cache: /var/lib/jenkins/.sonar/cache
[INFO] SonarQube version: 7.9.3
[INFO] Default locale: "en_US", source code encoding: "UTF-8"
[WARNING] SonarScanner will require Java 11 to run starting in SonarQube 8.x
[INFO] Load global settings
[INFO] Load global settings (done) | time=86ms
[INFO] Server id: 0697A0C6-AXLFaD-v57HRhyHJwu5i
[INFO] User cache: /var/lib/jenkins/.sonar/cache
[INFO] Load/download plugins
[INFO] Load plugins index
[INFO] Load plugins index (done) | time=55ms
[INFO] Plugin [l10nzh] defines 'l10nen' as base plugin. This metadata can be removed from manifest of l10n plugins since version 5.2.
[INFO] Load/download plugins (done) | time=83ms
[INFO] Process project properties
[INFO] Execute project builders
[INFO] Execute project builders (done) | time=5ms
[INFO] Project key: szyh_apps
[INFO] Base dir: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/sonar/ ****
[INFO] Working dir: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/sonar/ **** /target/sonar
[INFO] Load project settings for component key: 'szyh_apps'
[INFO] Load project settings for component key: 'szyh_apps' (done) | time=14ms
[INFO] Load quality profiles
[INFO] Load quality profiles (done) | time=51ms
[INFO] Detected Jenkins
[INFO] Load active rules
[INFO] Load active rules (done) | time=567ms
[INFO] Indexing files...
[INFO] Project configuration:
[INFO] Indexing files of module '******'
[INFO]   Base dir: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/sonar/ ****
[INFO]   Source paths: pom.xml, src/main/java
[INFO]   Test paths: src/test/java
...
[INFO] Indexing files of module '****(the aggregator project)****'
[INFO]   Base dir: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/sonar/ ****
[INFO]   Source paths: pom.xml
[INFO] 1 file indexed
[INFO] 0 files ignored because of scm ignore settings
[INFO] Quality profile for xml: Sonar way
[INFO] ------------- Run sensors on module ****
[INFO] Load metrics repository
[INFO] Load metrics repository (done) | time=16ms
[INFO] Sensor JavaXmlSensor [java]
[INFO] Sensor JavaXmlSensor [java] (done) | time=1ms
[INFO] Sensor JaCoCo XML Report Importer [jacoco]
[INFO] Sensor JaCoCo XML Report Importer [jacoco] (done) | time=3ms
[INFO] ------------- Run sensors on module ****
[INFO] Sensor JavaXmlSensor [java]
[INFO] Sensor JavaXmlSensor [java] (done) | time=0ms
[INFO] Sensor JaCoCo XML Report Importer [jacoco]
[INFO] Sensor JaCoCo XML Report Importer [jacoco] (done) | time=1ms
...
[INFO] Sensor MyBatisLint Sensor [mybatis]
[INFO] stmtIdExcludeList: []
[INFO] Sensor MyBatisLint Sensor [mybatis] (done) | time=78ms
[INFO] Sensor JavaXmlSensor [java]
[INFO] 1 source files to be analyzed
[INFO] Load project repositories
[INFO] Load project repositories (done) | time=16ms
[INFO] Sensor JavaXmlSensor [java] (done) | time=172ms
[INFO] 1/1 source files have been analyzed
[INFO] Sensor HTML [web]
[INFO] Sensor HTML [web] (done) | time=13ms
[INFO] Sensor XML Sensor [xml]
[INFO] 1 source files to be analyzed
[INFO] Sensor XML Sensor [xml] (done) | time=143ms
[INFO] Sensor JaCoCo XML Report Importer [jacoco]
[INFO] 1/1 source files have been analyzed
[INFO] Sensor JaCoCo XML Report Importer [jacoco] (done) | time=2ms
[INFO] ------------- Run sensors on project
[INFO] Sensor Zero Coverage Sensor
[INFO] Sensor Zero Coverage Sensor (done) | time=0ms
[INFO] SCM provider for this project is: git
[INFO] 1 files to be analyzed
[INFO] 1/1 files analyzed
[INFO] Calculating CPD for 0 files
[INFO] CPD calculation finished
[INFO] Analysis report generated in 70ms, dir size=191 KB
[INFO] Analysis report compressed in 9ms, zip size=16 KB
[INFO] Analysis report uploaded in 20ms
[INFO] ANALYSIS SUCCESSFUL, you can browse http:// **** /dashboard?id=szyh_apps
[INFO] Note that you will be able to access the updated dashboard once the server has processed the submitted analysis report
[INFO] More about the report processing at http:// **** /api/ce/task?id=****
[INFO] Analysis total time: 5.244 s
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO]
```

[image: In SonarQube，only pom.xml]

disabled scm can work, but no time and author information

```sh
mvn jacoco:prepare-agent sonar:sonar \
  -Dsonar.projectKey=szyh_apps \
  -Dsonar.host.url=http://**** \
  -Dsonar.login=**** \
  -Dsonar.scm.disabled \
  -s /usr/share/maven/conf/settings-szyh_apps.xml
```

Comment: Are you updating he git submodules?

Comment: yes，I set update in jenkins, file exists in submodule directory, jacoco can work.
It may be that SonarQube does not support Git submodules

Comment: Did you try to use `-Dsonar.sources=<root>` parameter?

Comment: I just tried it and it still doesn’t work.

Answer (score 1):

you can set -Dsonar.scm.exclusions.disabled=true in cmd line or
from SonarQube Dashboard->Administration->General settings->SCM->Disable the scm sensor=TRUE

This is working fine for me, I am using SonarQube V7.9.5

This is something related with how git is reading your repo.
first try cmd in you repository: git ls-tree -r HEAD

You can refer to Ann's answer :https://community.sonarsource.com/t/no-results-for-git-submodules/8464:
"""
Looking at the source of sonar-scm-git-plugin, I understand that actually it’s not strictly "adding exclusions based on project’s .gitignore", but instead it’s ignoring every file that’s not managed by the root repository.

You can verify this running ***git ls-tree -r HEAD*** in your git repo. The submodule’s files are not listed and basically this is what the Git Plugin 1.8 is doing.
"""